# specified method is not supported error on calling grpc service using protobuf-net library

Tags: c#, grpc, protobuf-net, grpc-dotnet, protobuf-net.grpc

My team uses Google grpc communication for micro service communication. I came across protobuf-net that is fast, reduces code complexity and no .proto file to be defined. I wanted to give a try using protobuf-net to see if we gain considerable performance improvement. However, I am getting error "specified method is not supported". I think I am not able to mark the entity correctly. I can use @marc-gravel help to understand the problem. Here are the details of my dotnet code

```
[ProtoContract]
public class ProtoBufInput
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public Building BuildingObj { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public byte[] Payload { get; set; }

    public ProtoBufInput(string id, Building buildingObj, byte[] payload)
    {
        BuildingObj = buildingObj;
        Id = id;
        Payload = payload;
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ProtoBufResult
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public int RandomNumber { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public bool RandomBool { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    public IList<string> ErrorMessages { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    public Building BuildingObj { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(6)]
    public string RandomString { get; set; }

    public ProtoBufResult()
    {
        RandomNumber = 0;
        RandomBool = false;
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class Building : Component<BuildingMetadata>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string tag { get; set; }
} 

[ProtoContract]
public class BuildingMetadata : ComponentMetadata
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public BuildingType Type { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public bool IsAttached { get; set; }

    public override object Clone()
    {
        var baseClone = base.Clone() as ComponentMetadata;
        return new BuildingMetadata()
        {
            Model = baseClone.Model,
            PropertyMetadata = baseClone.PropertyMetadata,
        };
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public enum BuildingType
{
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ComponentMetadata : ICloneable
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public IDictionary<string, PropertyMetadata> PropertyMetadata { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, PropertyMetadata>();

    public virtual object Clone()
    {
        return new ComponentMetadata()
        {
            Model = Model,
            PropertyMetadata = PropertyMetadata.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.Clone() as PropertyMetadata),
        };
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class PropertyMetadata : ICloneable
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public JToken Value { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    [JsonProperty("Version")]
    public int Version { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    [JsonProperty("backVersion")]
    public int BackVersion { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    [JsonProperty("backCode")]
    public int BackCode { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    [JsonProperty("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(6)]
    [JsonProperty("createTime")]
    public string CreateTime { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new PropertyMetadata()
        {
            CreateTime = CreateTime ?? DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o"),
        };
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Component<ComponentMetadata>))]
public class Component<TMetadataType> : ComponentBase, IComponent where TMetadataType : ComponentMetadata, new()
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public TMetadataType Metadata { get; set; } = new TMetadataType();

    public string Model => Metadata.Model;

    public IEnumerable<(string, IComponent)> ListComponents() => Components.Select(x => (x.Key, x.Value as IComponent));

    public IEnumerable<(string, JToken)> ListProperties() => Properties.Select(x => (x.Key, x.Value));

    public ComponentMetadata GetMetadata() => Metadata;

    public bool TryGetComponent(string name, out IComponent component)
    {
        component = null;
        if (!Components.TryGetValue(name, out var innerComponent))
        {
            return false;
        }

        component = innerComponent as IComponent;
        return true;
    }

    public bool TryGetProperty(string name, out JToken property) => Properties.TryGetValue(name, out property);
}

[ProtoContract]
public class ComponentBase
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public IDictionary<string, JToken> Properties { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public IDictionary<string, InnerComponent> Components { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, InnerComponent>();
}

[ProtoContract]
public class InnerComponent : Component<ComponentMetadata>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string tag { get; set; }
}
```

Now coming to the service class and its implementation, I have something like this

```
[ServiceContract]
public interface IProtoBufService
{
    [OperationContract]
    public Task<ProtoBufResult> ProcessPb(ProtoBufInput input, CallContext context = default);
}

public class ProtoBufService : IProtoBufService
{
    public Task<ProtoBufResult> ProcessPb(ProtoBufInput protoBufInput, CallContext context)
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

Rest of the configuration in start up file is correct like adding

```
serviceCollection.AddCodeFirstGrpc();
builder.MapGrpcService<Services.V2.ProtoBufService>();
```

Comment: I can try to look later, but my first guess would be the dictionary with `JToken`. That's not going to be protobuf compatible. Did the error message not give any additional context?

Comment: Thanks for taking a look. I too think that JToken is not protobuf compatible. How do I overcome this? If I look at TargetSite attribute of exception, then I see

`Method System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.get_IsCollectible cannot be called in this context.
Method System.Reflection.MethodBase.get_IsConstructedGenericMethod cannot be called in this context.
Method System.Reflection.MemberInfo.get_CustomAttributes cannot be called in this context.`
Also, the data part of exception has `{System.Collections.ListDictionaryInternal}` so it might be JToken

Comment: `Properties` looks to be meant to represent free-form JSON content, so couldn't you just make some surrogate `string` property and serialize that?  `[ProtoMember(1)] string SerializedProperties { get => JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Properties); set => Properties = value == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, JToken>>(value); }`

Comment: If I replace the `JToken` properties with string surrogates, those properties can be serialized successfully.  See https://dotnetfiddle.net/zHHlCI.

Comment: However, there is another problem, namely that runtime type model generation will crash with a null reference exception unless `[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Component<ComponentMetadata>))]` is removed from `Component<TMetadataType>`, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/CzFf7P.  Why do you need that?  Your question is missing a definition for `IComponent` so it's impossible for us to guess why you need that `ProtoInclude` or how to fix it.  Maybe you should split this into two simpler questions, one for `JToken` and one for the ProtoInclude problem, each with a [mcve]?

Comment: totally agree with the string proxy suggestion here - I'd go with something like https://gist.github.com/mgravell/19e705577a60d2d99ea8e05b6becd25e - as for the ProtoInclude: intent is unclear, and you have two things with field 1, which is invalid - I'd need to understand what you're trying to do there to comment

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. I removed the reference `[ProtoInclude(1, typeof(Component<ComponentMetadata>))]`. Can you tell me what is the use of "ProtoInclude"? However, I am still facing errors while creating "Building" object and verifying all its properties. What am I missing? - https://dotnetfiddle.net/oPrBHz

Comment: You really need a [mcve] for your second problem that is independent of the `JToken` problem.  I tried to create one here: https://dotnetfiddle.net/pyD024.  And here I tried to add the appropriate `[ProtoContract]` attributes -- but it crashes inside the serializer: https://dotnetfiddle.net/5KVBOn.

Comment: Oh look.  Adding a private setter for `Component<TMetadataType>.Model` seems to fix the final problem, see https://dotnetfiddle.net/FjDDsB.  I'll try to write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have three problems with your serialization code:

1. As [noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73767478/specified-method-is-not-supported-error-on-calling-grpc-service-using-protobuf-n#comment130264492_73767478) by [Marc Gravell](https://stackoverflow.com/users/23354/marc-gravell), Protobuf-net does not know how to serialize Json.NET's `JToken` objects.

   Since `JToken` objects are intended to represent free-form JSON, the easiest way to serialize them with Protobuf-net is to serialize surrogate `string` properties instead that represent the raw JSON value:

   ```
   [ProtoContract]
   public class PropertyMetadata : ICloneable
   {
       [ProtoMember(1)]
       string SerializedValue { get => Value?.ToString(Formatting.None); set => Value = (value == null ? null : JToken.Parse(value)); } // FIXED
   ```

   and

   ```
   public class ComponentBase
   {
       [ProtoMember(1)]
       string SerializedProperties { get => Properties == null ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Properties); set => Properties = (value == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, JToken>>(value)); }
   ```

   Note I am serializing the entire `IDictionary<string, JToken> Properties` object as a single JSON object.
2. When serializing an inheritance hierarchy, Protobuf-net requires that every base class `TBase` be informed of the existence of all immediate derived classes `TDerived`.  This can be done via attributes by adding

   ```
   [ProtoContract]
   [ProtoInclude(N, typeof(TDerived))] 
   public class TBase { }
   ```

   to the base class.  Note that the numbers `N` must be unique and not overlap with any [`ProtoMemberAttribute.Tag`](https://github.com/protobuf-net/protobuf-net/blob/main/src/protobuf-net.Core/ProtoMemberAttribute.cs#L40) values so it is wise to start them from a large number such as 1000:

   ```
   [ProtoContract]
   [ProtoInclude(1001, typeof(BuildingMetadata))] 
   public class ComponentMetadata : ICloneable
   ```

   ```
   [ProtoContract]
   [ProtoInclude(1002, typeof(Building))] 
   [ProtoInclude(1001, typeof(InnerComponent))] 
   public class Component<TMetadataType> : ComponentBase, IComponent where TMetadataType : ComponentMetadata, new()
   ```

   ```
   [ProtoContract]
   [ProtoInclude(1002, typeof(Component<BuildingMetadata>))] 
   [ProtoInclude(1001, typeof(Component<ComponentMetadata>))] 
   public class ComponentBase
   ```
3. In your [demo fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/oPrBHz), your class `Component<TMetadataType>` has a get-only property `Model` which you are serializing:

   ```
   [ProtoMember(2)]
   public string Model => Metadata.Model;
   ```

   With the other two problems fixed, for some reason this property causes the serializer to throw the following exception:

   ```
   System.InvalidOperationException: Unable to wrap ComponentBase/ComponentBase: Unable to bind serializer: It was not possible to prepare a serializer for: ComponentBase (ProtoBuf.Internal.Serializers.InheritanceTypeSerializer`2[ComponentBase,ComponentBase])
   ```

   This can be resolved by either removing `Model` from serialization, or adding a private dummy setter like so:

   ```
   [ProtoMember(2)]
   public string Model { get => Metadata.Model; private set { } } // Private set required for serialization
   ```

Complete modified classes here:

```
[ProtoContract]
public class Building : Component<BuildingMetadata>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Id { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string tag { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class InnerComponent : Component<ComponentMetadata>
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    [JsonIgnore]
    public string tag { get; set; }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class BuildingMetadata : ComponentMetadata
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public BuildingType Type { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public bool IsAttached { get; set; }

    public override object Clone()
    {
        var baseClone = base.Clone() as ComponentMetadata;
        return new BuildingMetadata()
        {
            Model = baseClone.Model,
            PropertyMetadata = baseClone.PropertyMetadata,
        };
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public enum BuildingType
{
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1001, typeof(BuildingMetadata))] 
public class ComponentMetadata : ICloneable
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public string Model { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public IDictionary<string, PropertyMetadata> PropertyMetadata { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, PropertyMetadata>();

    public virtual object Clone()
    {
        return new ComponentMetadata()
        {
            Model = Model,
            PropertyMetadata = PropertyMetadata.ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value.Clone() as PropertyMetadata),
        };
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public class PropertyMetadata : ICloneable
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    string SerializedValue { get => Value?.ToString(Formatting.None); set => Value = (value == null ? null : JToken.Parse(value)); } // FIXED

    [JsonProperty("Value")]
    public JToken Value { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    [JsonProperty("Version")]
    public int Version { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(3)]
    [JsonProperty("backVersion")]
    public int BackVersion { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(4)]
    [JsonProperty("backCode")]
    public int BackCode { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(5)]
    [JsonProperty("Description")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ProtoMember(6)]
    [JsonProperty("createTime")]
    public string CreateTime { get; set; }

    public object Clone()
    {
        return new PropertyMetadata()
        {
            CreateTime = CreateTime ?? DateTime.UtcNow.ToString("o"),
        };
    }
}

[ProtoContract]
public interface IComponent
{
    ComponentMetadata GetMetadata();

    IEnumerable<(string name, IComponent component)> ListComponents();

    IEnumerable<(string name, JToken property)> ListProperties();

    bool TryGetProperty(string name, out JToken property);

    bool TryGetComponent(string name, out IComponent component);
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1002, typeof(Building))] 
[ProtoInclude(1001, typeof(InnerComponent))] 
public class Component<TMetadataType> : ComponentBase, IComponent where TMetadataType : ComponentMetadata, new()
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    public TMetadataType Metadata { get; set; } = new TMetadataType();

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public string Model { get => Metadata.Model; private set { } } // Private set required for serialization

    public IEnumerable<(string, IComponent)> ListComponents() => Components.Select(x => (x.Key, x.Value as IComponent));

    public IEnumerable<(string, JToken)> ListProperties() => Properties.Select(x => (x.Key, x.Value));

    public ComponentMetadata GetMetadata() => Metadata;

    public bool TryGetComponent(string name, out IComponent component)
    {
        component = null;
        if (!Components.TryGetValue(name, out var innerComponent))
        {
            return false;
        }

        component = innerComponent as IComponent;
        return true;
    }

    public bool TryGetProperty(string name, out JToken property) => Properties.TryGetValue(name, out property);
}

[ProtoContract]
[ProtoInclude(1002, typeof(Component<BuildingMetadata>))] 
[ProtoInclude(1001, typeof(Component<ComponentMetadata>))] 
public class ComponentBase
{
    [ProtoMember(1)]
    string SerializedProperties { get => Properties == null ? null : JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Properties); set => Properties = (value == null ? null : JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, JToken>>(value)); }

    public IDictionary<string, JToken> Properties { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, JToken>();

    [ProtoMember(2)]
    public IDictionary<string, InnerComponent> Components { get; set; } = new Dictionary<string, InnerComponent>();
}
```

Fixed working fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/zaLmtR).